# The order of a *set* of elements (rather than the order of a single element)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In a group $G$, the *order* of an element $a \in G$, which I'll write $o(a)$, is the cardinality of the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ generated by $a$.

Instead of a single element $a$, we can generate a subgroup $\langle S \rangle$ from a *set* of elements $S \subseteq G$.

It seems natural to call the cardinality of $\langle S \rangle$ the **order** of the set $S \subseteq G$, written analogously as $o(S)$. So for instance, if $S$ generates all of $G$, then the order of $S$ is the order of $G$, and if $S$ contains a single element, then its order is the order of that element.

After a quick search through some texts and google, I'm not finding anything written about this idea, and I'm just wondering if there are any actually interesting results that come from making this definition.

Some obvious things that come to mind, that suggest the kind of results I'm asking about, might be:

- subadditivity is sometimes true: $o(S) \leq \sum_{a \in S} o(a)$.
- $S \subseteq T \implies o(S) \leq o(T)$ (but not vice-versa)
- Besides the obvious $|S| \leq o(S)$, $|S|$ seems largely unrelated to $o(S)$

and so on. Just a reference would be a fine answer to this question.

Comment: Subadditivity is not true. If your group is abelian you get $o(S) \leq \prod o(a)$. However, you have nothing similar to a bound in the non-abelian case. Take the infinite group with presentation $\langle x,y | x^2 = y^2 = e \rangle$. Then, $x$ and $y$ span an infinite group although they have finite order.

Comment: I had just realized that myself and was editing the question. Thanks!!

Comment: let's not focus too much on the brainstorming part of my question :)  I'm looking for references to work that has already considered this definition of $o(S)$. Thanks for reading closely however!

Comment: While you are correct that this is in some sense a natural generalization,  it probably has not been define because it has little use.

Comment: The real operation which is interesting is $S\to\langle S\rangle.$ That is a closure operation.In particular, it is a finitary closure operator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator

Comment: Interestingly, we don't tend to define order of single elements in semigroups, even though your definition works there.  The order of an element is actually more like an ordinal number, than a cardinal number - the first/smallest  $n>0$ so that $a^n=1.$

Comment: Why haven't you edited out subadditivity from your question, now that you know it is false? It is really the only interesting property that you assert.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Order of elements in a semigroup goes back to at least the 1960s with the analogous definition to the one here (reference given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1764022/10513) by an editor of Semigroup Forum).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I did edit it, to say "is sometimes true". Further, it is possible to define the order of an element as the cardinality of the subgroup it generates. And once more, this is not the focus of the question. I'm not asserting facts about anything, I'm asking if any work has been done on the consequences of making this definition. I then listed some simple things that came to mind as a jumping off point for what might be considered such a consequence.

Comment: Being "sometimes true" is hardly interest. It isn't even true for very basic examples with $|S|=2.$ Lots of things are sometimes true.

Comment: Thomas, please read the question again, and my comments. This discussion is not actually helpful!

Comment: My comments are on why you won't likely find a reference to such a definition. They are not irrelevant. My question is, "Why would anybody define this?" Definitions are not mandatory. We define things because they are useful, and one reason they are useful is if they have useful properties. You have listed properties that are not very useful, not true, or are simple extensions of algebraic closure operators.

Comment: Once again, the question is not actually about those specific things I wrote. I included them for context, to make it more obvious what kinds of answers I'm looking for. I agree that they're not very interesting -- that's why I was able to think of them immediately. If you don't know of any references, and aren't interested in looking for them, then there's little reason for you to be here. Thanks!

Comment: And again, my comments are on why you won't get a reference - an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This notion is used a lot. It is simply called "the order of the subgroup generated by $S$" and denoted $|\langle S\rangle|$. The name and especially notation are short enough that there is no need for a "shortcut" (your new notation $o(S)$ is barely shorter than the already existing one).

Generally, there is not much relation between $|\langle S\rangle|$ and $|S|$, or the order of the elements of $S$.